# Connecting Airoha SDK AAR Files in Flutter for Airoha Chip Earbud Communication

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sdk, flutter-native

I'm working on a Flutter project where I need to establish communication between a Flutter app and Airoha chip-based earbuds. Airoha provides an SDK in AAR (Android Archive) format, which contains the necessary functionalities to interact with the earbuds. However, I'm facing challenges in integrating this AAR file into my Flutter project.

I've already gone through the Flutter documentation and tried to use platform channels for this purpose, but I'm having trouble connecting and using the Airoha SDK from Flutter.

Thank you for your assistance!

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

I've added the AAR file provided by Airoha to the android/app/libs directory.
I've made the necessary changes in my build.gradle and settings.gradle files to include the AAR file.
I've tried to create a platform channel to communicate with the Airoha SDK, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.
I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to properly integrate the Airoha SDK AAR file into my Flutter project and establish communication with the Airoha chip earbuds. If there are any code examples or sample projects that can help me get started, that would be highly valuable.

Comment: Check Flutter Platform channel implementation, also, where do you get the SDK for airoha, i've been looking for it too